# Is this the right way to do a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a search box for each status of an item!

When I search, is this the right way to do it?

```
SELECT *
FROM (`site_pages`)
WHERE  `title`  LIKE '%php%'
OR  `content`  LIKE '%php%'
HAVING `status` != 'deleted'
AND `status` != 'concept'
```

When no search is committed I just use

```
... WHERE'status' != 'deleted' AND 'status' != 'concept'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possibilities for improvement:

- There is no reason to use `having`, you should simply append additional `where` conditions.
- You could create a `statuses` table, assigning numeric representations for the deleted/concept values, allowing you to easily change the name of a status add/enumerate all existing statuses. This reduces the overhead of storing many redundant text fields, and drastically improves the speed of comparisons against the status field, numeric comparisons being far faster than string comparisons.
- You also might want to make the "deleted" status into a column on each record. As it stands, a record can be a concept, or delete, but not a deleted concept. What if you want to *undelete* a record? You've lost its pre-deletion status. This is how non-destructive deletion of records is typically done; either by activating a `deleted` bit, or deactivating an `active` bit.

Otherwise it looks like pretty standard SQL.

Comment: Your right! i was looking at it all wrong. I'm gonna make separate collums for the delete and concept status. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`HAVING` is used for aggregate queries (that is, queries that use `GROUP BY`). Your final two conditions should be merged into your `WHERE` block. Additionally, I don't think you need the parenthesis around the table name.

You'll find that as your data grows, using `LIKE` like that may not perform particularly well, but there's nothing syntatically wrong with how you're using it.